Setting root directory for projects and autochdir if file is not inside a project?
I just did a bunch of searching, and basically I want to be able to declare root directories for project (ideally on-the-fly with : commands rather than in my config file), (which I can do with Telescope project) and automatically change directories when I switch buffers.
So:

if the file is inside a folder inside a project folder, then set the directory to that and
if not then set the dir to the file's directory.

Project.nvim can change directories to project folders, but it overwrites autochdir to false, there's an issue, and a pull request for it. I installed it and disabled the override, but then it stops changing to project directories, and the plugin doesn't let me manually add project dirs anyway.

My recommendation for that is: vim-rooter.
With the following settings vim-rooter will have the desired behavior:
let g:rooter_change_directory_for_non_project_files = 'current'


That works, though I would prefer a plugin with a : command to add directories permanently, without reloading the vim config.

Thanks fir the feedback. I don't have to reload the Vim configuration. I just add a .gitignore file in the root and reload the file (: e %) to force Vim to change the current working directory.

I tried vim-rooter but came across this bug where directory patterns don't work: https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter/issues/138. I looked at project.nvim: https://github.com/ahmedkhalf/project.nvim and am going with that. I'll keep this question open and hopefully get responses for plugins that allow for adding directories with : commands.
